# docker-compose is not working after changing a volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq, docker-volume

Below is a part of my initial docker-compose file.

```
  st2sensorcontainer:
    image: ${ST2_IMAGE_REPO:-stackstorm/}st2sensorcontainer:${ST2_VERSION:-3.3.0}
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - st2api
    networks:
      - private
    dns_search: .
    volumes:
      - ./files/st2.docker.conf:/etc/st2/st2.docker.conf:ro
      - ./files/st2.user.conf:/etc/st2/st2.user.conf:ro
      - stackstorm-virtualenvs:/opt/stackstorm/virtualenvs:ro
      - stackstorm-packs:/opt/stackstorm/packs:ro
      - stackstorm-packs-configs:/opt/stackstorm/configs:ro
      - ${ST2_PACKS_DEV:-./packs.dev}:/opt/stackstorm/packs.dev:ro
  st2timersengine:
    image: ${ST2_IMAGE_REPO:-stackstorm/}st2timersengine:${ST2_VERSION:-3.3.0}
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - st2api
    networks:
      - private
    dns_search: .
    volumes:
      - ./files/st2.docker.conf:/etc/st2/st2.docker.conf:ro
  st2client:
    image: ${ST2_IMAGE_REPO:-stackstorm/}st2actionrunner:${ST2_VERSION:-3.3.0}
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - st2auth
      - st2api
      - st2stream
    command: /st2client-startup.sh
    networks:
      - private
    environment:
      ST2CLIENT: 1
      ST2_AUTH_URL: ${ST2_AUTH_URL:-http://st2auth:9100/}
      ST2_API_URL: ${ST2_API_URL:-http://st2api:9101/}
      ST2_STREAM_URL: ${ST2_STREAM_URL:-http://st2stream:9102/}
    volumes:
      - ./files/st2.docker.conf:/etc/st2/st2.docker.conf:ro
      - ./files/st2.user.conf:/etc/st2/st2.user.conf:ro
      - stackstorm-keys:/etc/st2/keys:rw
      - stackstorm-packs-configs:/opt/stackstorm/configs:rw
      - stackstorm-packs:/opt/stackstorm/packs:rw
      - ${ST2_PACKS_DEV:-./packs.dev}:/opt/stackstorm/packs.dev:rw
      - ./files/st2-cli.conf:/root/.st2/config
      - ./scripts/st2client-startup.sh:/st2client-startup.sh
  # external services
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.0
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - private
    volumes:
      - stackstorm-mongodb:/data/db
    dns_search: .
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - private
    dns_search: .
    volumes:
      - stackstorm-rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq
  redis:
    image: redis:6.0
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - private
    dns_search: .
    volumes:
      - stackstorm-redis:/data

volumes:
    stackstorm-mongodb:
    stackstorm-rabbitmq:
    stackstorm-redis:
    stackstorm-postgres:
    stackstorm-packs:
    stackstorm-packs-configs:
    stackstorm-keys:
    stackstorm-virtualenvs:
    stackstorm-ssh:

networks:
  public:
    driver: bridge
  private:
    driver: bridge
```

I've changed the last lines of the above file as below.

```
# external services
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.0
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - private
    volumes:
      - /opt/st2/mongodb-src:/data/db
    dns_search: .
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - private
    dns_search: .
    volumes:
      - /opt/st2/rabbitmq-src:/var/lib/rabbitmq
  redis:
    image: redis:6.0
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - private
    dns_search: .
    volumes:
      - /opt/st2/redis-src:/data

volumes:
    stackstorm-postgres:
    stackstorm-packs:
    stackstorm-packs-configs:
    stackstorm-keys:
    stackstorm-virtualenvs:
    stackstorm-ssh:

networks:
  public:
    driver: bridge
  private:
    driver: bridge
```

with the initial docker-compose setup, the container setup was working fine. But after i've removed redis,rabbitmq and mongodb volumes from the volume tag and pointed those into a location in my host, the below error is occuring. Could someone please help?

`st2api_1               | 2021-01-21 08:31:48,166 ERROR [-] Connections to RabbitMQ cannot be re-established: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED`

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [mcve]?  Remove all of the containers and options that aren't necessary to demonstrate the issue.  Also verify if the RabbitMQ container is actually starting up, or just hasn't started up yet, and see if there's anything interesting in _its_ logs.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze i've adjusted the code and yes rabbitmq container is starting properly without any issue. Error is occurring when i change the volume.